# sending global variable in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have set a global variable from the data coming from a jquery. and save that data in a global variable as :

```
 var window.globalname = data;  // variable value set in another ajax call
```

i want to send this global variable through another ajax call then how should i write ??
i have written :

```
type:'POST', // ajax call
url:'url'
data: {name="globalname"} or data :{name="$globalname"}
```

i want to know how to write this data ??

Comment: Eh... `data: {name: window.globalname}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, (almost) NEVER use global variables in JavaScript. You pollute your global scope.

As to your question, try the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'url',
  data: {name: window.globalname},
});
```